# How to show ProgressIndicator in center of Pane in Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a Pane with some controls and a button. When I click on the button, I want show ProgressIndicator in center of pane without removing any controls.

When I am adding a ProgressIndicator to pane during `onAction` of button, it adds it below the button. I want it to overlay on the pane.

The picture below explains what I want.

[image: progress indicator]

**Code**

```
package fx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
    final VBox bx = new VBox();
    bx.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    TextField userName = new TextField("User Name");
    userName.setMaxWidth(200);
    TextField email = new TextField("Email");
    email.setMaxWidth(200);
    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
            //adding here but it is adding at below of button
            //how to do here
            bx.getChildren().add(pi);
            //Further process
          }
    });
    bx.getChildren().addAll(userName, email, submit);
    Scene c = new Scene(bx);
    arg0.setScene(c);
    arg0.setMinWidth(500);
    arg0.setMinHeight(500);
    arg0.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Main h = new Main();
     h.launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) as your root layout instead of using a VBox. StackPane allows you to stack nodes on top of each other (z-order).

On the button's action you can create a new ProgressIndicator and add it to your StackPane. I have introduced another VBox as the parent to the indicator, because I did not want the indicator to capture all the available space. You can `disable` the already present VBox to get the `greying` effect on button's action after the process is done you can enable the VBox again.

[image]

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        VBox bx = new VBox();
        bx.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField userName = new TextField("User Name");
        userName.setMaxWidth(200);
        TextField email = new TextField("Email");
        email.setMaxWidth(200);
        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
                VBox box = new VBox(pi);
                box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                // Grey Background
                bx.setDisable(true);
                root.getChildren().add(box);
            }
        });
        bx.getChildren().addAll(userName, email, submit);
        root.getChildren().add(bx);
        Scene c = new Scene(root);
        arg0.setScene(c);
        arg0.setMinWidth(500);
        arg0.setMinHeight(500);
        arg0.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine, but the overlay to show the gray i had to add the vbox in my layout because the   one bx.setDisable(true); wont be enough to show the gray also i added the loading text using   Text label = new Text("Loading... Please wait");
        label.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        label.setFill(Color.BLACK);

Comment: This would not work when you want some other work on button click. For example, `ProcessIndicator` should show on login button click and hide after user validation. Because it open only after current thread completion.