# JavaFX Cursor wait while loading new anchorPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to load a new anchorPane in the existing scene by removing the old anchorPane.Now i need to show the user that loading cursor and the action performed by the user should not happen(like button click or key press).

I have used but Cursor.WAIT but still the action can be performed.

> anchorPane.getScene().SetCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

```
    HomeController controller=new HomeController(stage,anchorPane);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/home.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root=(Parent) loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Message is " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    anchorPane.getChildren().remove(0);
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(root);
```

I have added Cursor.WAIT before this code.but i doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at [How to show ProgressIndicator in center of Pane in Javafx...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794379/how-to-show-progressindicator-in-center-of-pane-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor.WAIT change only the icon of your cursor but it doesn't prevent you to interact with your view. If you want to prevent an user to interact with your view your could disable the elements like btn.setEnabled(false).

To show the user that you are peforming some background actions and he/she should wait until it's complete use tasks and dialogs.

```
   Task task = new Task(new Runnable() { ... do stuff ... });
   Dialog dialog = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
   dialog.setTitle("Wait");
   dialog.disableButton(ButtonType.OK); 
   task.stateProperty().addListener(
            (observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED
                        || newState == Worker.State.FAILED
                        || newState == Worker.State.CANCELLED) {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            });
    new Thread(task).start();
    dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Without disabling can't I do something else.So that the user can know its loading?

Comment: i have tried this but now i need to open a dialog inside a thread .Can i do so? I done it was throwing error.